# Keymapping issues with ctrl+z VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, keymapping

I am having issues with my Undo, Key Mapping function. It's default is ctrl+z which is exactly what I want but the shortcut key does not work. The same goes for the Redo key (which is ctrl+y/ctrl+shift+z). When i tried remapping the key, it does not even let me type in ctrl+Z respectively. I am able to type them separately, but when i try together it does not work. My ctrl+Z function works with literally every other application i have, so its not a keyboard issue.

FYI, my installed extensions are; Jupyter, Jupyter Keymap, Jupyter Notebook Renderers, Live Server, Pylance, and Python. I've already tried disabling Jupiter Keymap to see if that was the issue and it didn't make a difference

I've looked everywhere for an answer but no solution has been appropriate for me. Any help will be appreciated. I really don't want to have to switch to a different editor.

Comment: _"not even let me type in ctrl+Z respectively"_: does that mean you're pressing `Ctrl`, letting it go, and _then_ pressing `Z`? What do you mean by "remapping" the key? Can you describe the steps you took to remap it? Please [edit] your question to make it more clear; it's hard to know what the problem is without more information. See [ask] for information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin sorry i thought my question was thorough enough. But I cannot click the combination 'ctrl+z' but i am able to do 'ctrl' and 'z' separately. The problem seems to be that i cannot click a secondary key after clicking 'ctrl'

Comment: Have a look at the command `Developer: Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` and you can see what command, if any, vscode is resolving `ctrl+z` to.

Comment: When you click `Add Keybinding` you can not type in `ctrl` at all? such as `ctrl+p` except `ctrl+z`?

Comment: Can you comment all the settings in the keybindings.json?